# Почему пустой request при отправке Post запроса Python

Tags: python-3.x, requests, post

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import json
import requests
import re
import string
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Literal, Any, Optional, IO

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .updater.runner import runner

headers = {
    "cookie": "golden_key=golden_key(в cookies если залогинены)",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0",
}

work = Session()
first_result = work.get("https://funpay.com/", headers=headers)

# print( first_result.text )

work.get("https://funpay.com/chat/", headers=headers)
response = work.get("https://funpay.com/chat/?node=80949984", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
data_app_data = soup.find("body").get("data-app-data")

html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

data_orders = html.select("#live-counters")[0].get("data-orders")
node_tag = html.select(".chat.chat-float")[0].get("data-tag")
bookmarks_tag = html.select(".chat.chat-float")[0].get("data-bookmarks-tag")
# last_message_id = 

chat_message_list = []

for element in html.select('.chat-message-list'):
    message = html.select('.chat-message-list > .message.message-head')[0].get("id")
    chat_message_list.append(message)

last_message_id = chat_message_list[-1].split("-")[1]

print(data_orders)
print(node_tag)
print(bookmarks_tag)
print(last_message_id)
print("")

# print(data_app_data)
token = eval(data_app_data)

headers = {
    "cookie": "golden_key=1i4v9w8trbqrprxbpso612v8b830y22m",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
    
print(token["csrf-token"])

message_text = "Whatsapp"

request = {
    "action": "chat_message",
    "data": {"node": "users-8422892-8580826", "last_message": last_message_id, "content": message_text}
}

#{"type":"orders_counters","id":"8422892","tag": data_orders,"data":False},{"type":"chat_node","id":"users-8422892-8580826","tag": node_tag,"data":{"node":"users-8422892-8580826","last_message": last_message_id,"content": message_text}},{"type":"chat_bookmarks","id":"8422892","tag": bookmarks_tag,"data":False},{"type":"c-p-u","id":"8580826","tag":"1oyrsmw1","data":False}

objects = [
    {
        "type": "chat_node", 
        "id": "8422892-8580826", 
        "tag": node_tag, 
        "data": {"node": "users-8422892-8580826", "last_message": last_message_id, "content": ""}
    }
]

data = {
    "objects": json.dumps(objects),
    "request": json.dumps(request),
    "csrf_token": token
}

print(data['request'])

result = work.post("https://funpay.com/runner/", headers=headers, json=data)

print(result)
```